# Is it possible to segment data in QGIS by adding shapefiles and then exporting both as one (csv) dataset?

Tags: qgis, raster, spatial-statistics

I have this global temperature data set

https://1drv.ms/u/s!ArVyXA5cSMj2h6h0GCSsNGKCsAYpSg?e=bZUaxx

*(sorry it's almost 1GB, but [this light data set is much smaller](https://1drv.ms/u/s!ArVyXA5cSMj2h6hon9UH5s1k1U3VGQ?e=q4sSIR) and is very similar, if you just want to have a quick a look at what kind of datasets I'm working with)*

as well as these shapefiles: [GDL shapefiles V4](https://globaldatalab.org/shdi/shapefiles/)

This is what they look like in QGIS when put together:

[image]

Now, what I need is a dataframe that includes both datasets, something like this:

[image]

But with another row with the 1992 mean temperature data for each region.

Is it possible to do this with QGIS? Is there something like an "export" feature to convert the data into .csv format for example?

Comment: So you have a raster of temperature and a shapefiles with borders and some attributes? Try zonal statistics. To export as csv just right-click the layer

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I found the zonal statistics feature, selected the GDL shapefiles as the 'input layer' (as was suggested already by the program), ras_temp_1992 as the raster layer and then ran the process which took a while. After the new layer was created, I exported it as a .xlsx file (also pre selected), which resulted in this file: